# AWS dynamoDB - batchWrite - The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to write one row into my dynamodb table:
[image]

with this node code

```
   await this.dynamoDocumentClient.batchWrite({
     "RequestItems":{
       "Delivery_Cost_By_PostCode":[
         {
           "PutRequest":{
             "Item":{
               "postcode":{
                 "N":"1234"
               }
             }
           }
         }]
     }
   }).promise();
```

But I get this error `ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema`. I am not sure why. I have read the [syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html#DDB-CreateTable-request-AttributeDefinitions) resource

Comment: What JS library are you using? What is `this.dynamoDocumentClient`?

Comment: Hi Phil, its part of https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dynamodb-seed, I hardcoded data for https://github.com/arielschvartz/serverless-dynamodb-seed/blob/master/index.js#L97-L107 though, just for testing
 this._dynamoDocumentClient = new this.provider.sdk.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
        service: this.dynamodb,
      });

Answer (score 0):

removing the string around 1234, fixed it :)

```
await this.dynamoDocumentClient.batchWrite({
     "RequestItems":{
       "Delivery_Cost_By_PostCode":[
         {
           "PutRequest":{
             "Item":{
               "postcode":{
                 "N":1234
               }
             }
           }
         }]
     }
   }).promise();
```